# get HiddenField Value from javascript to use in code-behind WITHOUT A BUTTON NOR POSTBACK

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have an html page that has a link to an external javascript file namely `external.js` as follows

`<script type =" text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>`

The page includes an `<asp:HiddenField>` defined as `Hidden1`.

In my external .js file there is a function `passData()` which basically populates `Hidden1` with some values. The way I do it is as follows.

On **HTML**

`<script> passData("<%=Hidden1.ClientID%>") </script>`  then in `external.js`:

```
function passData(hiddenFieldID)
{
document.getElementByID(hiddenFieldID).Value = "Value";
}
```

What I have been trying for some while now is to get the value of `Hidden1` from my code behind in `vb.net` by using:

`Dim str = Hidden1.value`

However, with no luck. I have noticed that I should perform some sort of postback so that the value can be taken. However, what I am thinking of is that how on my html page the value of `Hidden1` is showing when I use `alert` and at the same time I am not able to retrieve it on `page_load` in my `.aspx` unless I perform a postback. In my application I am really eager to get it working without having the need to add a button to initialize postbacks. I need to get `Hidden1` value in my `.aspx` code-behind page in order to store it in a database. Any suggestions or ideas ?

Comment: The page_load event in the codebehind executes first - before the javascript executes. So if you reference your hidden variable in the page_load, it will not yet be set and will be blank or null. After the page is loaded and your javascript has ran and set your variable, there must be some event to trigger a postback or ajax if you want to execute server side code (codebehind) again. You should probably just convert your javascript calculations to VB and do your calculation for your hidden variable in the codebehind instead of in javascript if it isn't too complicated.

Comment: If i went for the Ajax option, would something like a `Timer` be a good idea ?